# Page not found Error every time a user register on wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I keep getting complaints from user of the website saying they are getting page not found error on some pages. I checked they are right every time.

When I go to permalinks settings and press save settings button problem solved. But again same error after sometime. When I checked I understood that whenever a user register on the website it triggers something which generates this problem. I am not an wordpress expert, I have started using it few months back.

How can I solve it??

website: http://www.connectvonnect.com

I tried everything, nothing seems to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated this without logging in (http://www.connectvonnect.com/terms-of-use-agreement/) had page not found when I loaded it.

Do you have any login plugins on your site? Often wordpress glitches can be caused by conflicting plugins, to troubleshoot this simply disable all plugins and re-enable one at a time and check if the error persists. If you troubleshoot your plugins down to a plugin conflict you can contact the plugin author with the issue, as they will know their code best.

Without much more information about your site I can only recommend checking your .htaccess file, and checking if the problem persists with permalinks turned off?